Swift JSON Decoding Error After Server Migration: Expected String but Found Number
I've recently migrated my Laravel API to a new server, and since then, I've encountered a recurring JSON decoding issue on the iOS (Swift) side of my application. The error message I'm getting is:

Error while decoding response: typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "type", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

The issue seems to stem from the type field in my JSON response, which is being sent as a number (e.g., 0, 1) but is expected as a string by Swift. Here’s a sample of the JSON response:
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "trailers listed",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Customer Trailer",
            "url": "https://xxxxx.com/uploads/trailers/xxxxx.mp4",
            "type": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Example Trailer",
            "url": "https://xxxxx.com/uploads/trailers/xxxxx.mp4",
            "type": 1
        }
    ]
}

And my code:
struct IntroVideoManagement {
    static let shared = IntroVideoManagement()
    
    func getIntroVideo(completion: @escaping (String?, GetIntroVideoResponse?) -> Void){
        let stringUrl = APPURL.getTrailers
        guard let authKey = UniversalFuncs.shared.getAuthKey() else {
            completion("Error", nil)
            return
        }
        let _headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json",
                                      "Accept": "application/json",
                                      "Authorization": "Bearer \(authKey)"]
        
        if let url = URL(string: stringUrl) {
            AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: _headers).responseData { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    do {
                        let asJSON = try JSONDecoder().decode(GetIntroVideoResponse.self, from: data)
                        if  !asJSON.status{
                            completion(asJSON.message, nil)
                            return
                        }
                        completion(nil, asJSON)
                    } catch {
                        print("Error while decoding response: " + String(describing: error) + " from: \(String(describing: String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)))")
                        completion(error.localizedDescription, nil)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    completion(error.localizedDescription, nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The problem is widespread across the project, and manually adjusting all the data types in Swift would be time-consuming. I'm looking for a more efficient solution, possibly server-side, that can handle this issue across the board.
What I’ve Tried So Far:
I attempted to modify the type fields in Swift to be Int instead of String, but this approach isn't feasible for the entire project as it would require significant time and effort.
I've adjusted the Laravel API response using JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES and JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE to ensure that slashes are not escaped, but this did not resolve the data type issue.
Is there a quick fix or best practice for handling this type of JSON decoding issue across an entire Swift project after such a server migration? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
As a note, this setup was working correctly on the old server.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Swift is a strongly typed language. This means that you have to fix the structs on the Swift side. If your server is sending a number then the receiving property in the Swift struct needs to be a numeric type (e.g. Int or Float). Alternatively fix your server since it seems that it has changed the api contract
